# volleyball points counter; logic of the loops

Tags: android

I want to know why my program doesn't work normaly? It should be a app for counting points during volleyball match. I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1. br1 and br2 are counters for the sets. counter1 and counter2 are counters for the points in the set.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;
    Button btn4;
    Button btn5;
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
    TextView text4;

    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;

    int br1;
    int br2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        for(br1=0, br2=0; br1<=3 || br2<=3; )
        {

             do { 
                if (v == btn1) {
                    counter1++;
                    text1.setText(Integer.toString(counter1));
                    text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                }
                if (v == btn2) {
                    counter1--;
                    text1.setText(Integer.toString(counter1));
                    text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }

                if (v == btn3) {
                    counter2++;
                    text2.setText(Integer.toString(counter2));
                    text2.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                }
                if (v == btn4) {
                    counter2--;
                    text2.setText(Integer.toString(counter2));
                    text2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }

                if (v == btn5) {
                    counter1 = 0;
                    counter2 = 0;
                    text1.setText(Integer.toString(counter1));
                    text2.setText(Integer.toString(counter2));
                    text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    text2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }

            } while (((counter1 - counter2 >= 2) || (counter2 - counter1 >= 2)) && (counter1 >= 25 || counter2 >= 25)); 

            if (counter1 > counter2) {
                br1++;
                text3.setText(Integer.toString(br1));
            } else {
                br2++;
                text4.setText(Integer.toString(br2));
            }

            counter1 = 0;
            counter2 = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If someone can help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: What do you mean by `my program doesn't work normaly`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the behavior you're seeing and the behavior you expect to see?

Comment: The emulator starts but when I click on the buttons nothing happens in the text fields. Before the loops (for, if, do-while) when I click on buttons everything was fine with the incrementation but I need some restrictions, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think loops isn't what you need here.
I suggest you can try something like

```
@Overwrite
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == btn1) {
        counter1++;
        text1.setText(Integer.toString(counter1));
        text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    }
    else if (v == btn2) {
        counter1--;
        text1.setText(Integer.toString(counter1));
        text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if (v == btn3) {
        counter2++;
        text2.setText(Integer.toString(counter2));
        text2.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    }
    else if (v == btn4) {
        counter2--;
        text2.setText(Integer.toString(counter2));
        text2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if (v == btn5) {
        counter1 = 0;
        counter2 = 0;
        text1.setText(Integer.toString(counter1));
        text2.setText(Integer.toString(counter2));
        text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        text2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }

    if(counter1 >= 25 && counter1 - counter2 >= 2) {
        br1++;
        text3.setText(Integer.toString(br1));
        counter1 = 0;
        counter2 = 0;
    }
    else if(counter2 >= 25 && counter2 - counter1 >=2) {
        br2++;
        text3.setText(Integer.toString(br2));
        counter1 = 0;
        counter2 = 0;
    }

    if(br1 - br2 > 2 || br2 - br1 > 2) {
        // handle end of the match
    }
}
```